# Data transfer to my own computer from a website host by the same computer

Tags: networking

I have a question about using a web site host in my computer, say Computer A, using any web server hosting application e.g : apache.  I connect to my website in my very same computer A, and request to download a file of size 1Mb, in otherwords, I am connecting to my own computer and want to download a file in my computer.  In addition, my internet access is bound by a proxy server in a way of gateway.   **The questions are - does the file transfer really exist? Or is it a local file copying between 2 location? Will my data packet go through the proxy, to the internet, and go back to the proxy and return to me?**

Thanks everyone who are watching this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't go off your computer at all if you're using an internal address.

However, if you use an external address (for instance an IP address or dynamic DNS), then it will go out to the DNS server, resolve the address, and at the very worst, connect to the external interface of your proxy.

Comment: If I type the website as http://locahost:8080/, it will not go out?

Comment: And If I use the ip address of my computer, it will go to the proxy server?

Comment: `localhost:8080` will definitely not generate any real network traffic, unless you have explicitly set a proxy for localhost connections. Using the network IP address may or may not generate real network traffic depending on whether your network stack is smart enough to recognize it as also being a local address or not.

Comment: can I use some software to check if there are any traffic while using an IP adress to connect to my own computer?

Comment: Depending on the operating system you're using, there are some tools you can use to monitor network traffic, ranging in ease of use.